# mapping automatically Box.com and Php

Tags: php, box-api, box

I am trying to design an Application which can create folder and retrieve that folder from `box.com` using `PHP`, I have tried lots of APIs but fail.

Also I want to create the folder with automatic authentication.

I have tried https://developers.box.com/docs/ but can't do automatic authentication.

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.box.com/oauth2/token");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,"Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,"POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 'Accept: application/json'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,array('client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&client_secret=MY_CLIENT_SECRET_KEY&grant_type=urn:box:oauth2:grant-type:provision&username=MY_EMAIL'));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    print_r($result);
```

- here i use my client id, secret key and my email id which are register in box.com

IT Gives Some Kind of error:

> {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"The client credentials
>   are invalid"}

Comment: can you explain what do you mean by "automatic authentication".Did you have "Read and write all files and folders" scope for creating folders in user account?

Comment: automatic authentication means log in detail are given and the app will authorized automatically.

when i am going to access folders the authorization popup displayed, once i authorized then it can easily access but. 

But i want that authorization is also done automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using this [BoxPHPAPI](http://www.ulhas.net/GitHub/BoxPHPAPI/). I have used it on a big enterprise app. You have to make sure first that you have a app created at developers.box.com.

Once that is done you can pass all that info to the BoxPHPAPI Class and it should handle your login and authentication.

If you plan on doing many API calls at once or rapid succession I recommended you use curl pooling. It speeds it up quite a bit. From about 4 seconds to under 1 (for 5+ API calls). You can see an [example of the pooling in this fork of the BoxPHPAPI](https://github.com/lukedubber/BoxPHPAPI/blob/master/library/BoxAPI.class.php#L335-L347).

I hope this helps!

Comment: Box just announced at their [2015 developer conference](http://www.boxdev2015.com) a new set of APIs, one for PHP also. So maybe hold tight for a bit and use their official one?